# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevelopmentDebugManifest'

Tags: android-studio-2.3

Please Help

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDevelopmentDebugManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.